# What does "Position Reconstruction" mean?

Tags: dark-matter, particle-detectors

What does "Position Reconstruction" mean in the context of Dark Matter detection? Specifically see e.g. the title of [arxiv:1112.1481](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1481). Does it refers to an actual position in the dark matter detecting device?

Comment: Probably, yes. What's the context you encountered this?

Comment: @rfl https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.1481.pdf  This one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this refers to the position of the interaction within the dark matter detector. This particular paper describes a setup that is quite common, in that arrays of photomultipliers record a signal from an event. Analyzing the hit pattern on that array allows the experimentalists to reconstruct the location of the original particle interaction. Note that this is just one example; other experiments use other techniques, from the pattern of charges collected on surface electrodes to optical hit patterns to time delays etc.